# About reading file

Tags: pascal, freepascal

```
  while (not eof(inputFile)) do begin 
     new(newNode); 
     read(inputFile, newNode^.student.index); 
     read(inputFile, temp); 
     newNode^.student.forename := ''; 
     read(inputFile, temp); 
     while (temp <> ' ') do begin 
newNode^.student.forename:=newNode^.student.forename+temp; {And what does this +temp mean } 
      read(inputFile, temp); 
     end; 
     newNode^.student.surname:= ''; 
     read(inputFile, temp); 
     while (temp <> ' ') do begin
```

Could someone please explain to me the line

```
   read(inputFile, temp)
```

Why do we need that temp variable and for what is it used ?

```
 temp:char;
```

Temp is a character type, and the program needs to read forename and surname of a student. Is line

```
   read(temp)
```

excess ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `temp: char;` is used to hold one character at a time, read from the file. Because first name and surname are separated by a space in the file, you need to detect that space, so you can assign the read characters to correct field of the student record.

If `temp` would be declared as, e.g. `string`, the whole line (after the index) would be read into the `forename` field.

A commented breakdown of reading the first name follows:

```
newNode^.student.forename := ''; // clear the forename field
read(inputFile, temp);           // read one character
while (temp <> ' ') do begin     // while the read character is not a space
  newNode^.student.forename:=newNode^.student.forename+temp; // concatenate with the field content
  read(inputFile, temp);         // read next character
end; 
// continue with rest of code when a space after the forename is detected
```

I don't understand your last question regarding `read(temp)`. There is no such line in the shown code. If you think it is excess, remove it and see what happens. Be sure to learn how to step through the running code in your debugger.

Comment: It was read(inputFile, temp)  As you explained to me above it reads only a character and then combines them into a word.